# Removing carriage returns from a text file using a DOS batch file

Tags: batch-file

In one text file I have this lines:

```
2014-10-09 00:00:00.000;1663;2014-10-09 12:38:46.000;A;"
                    ";0;0;E/272

2014-10-09 00:00:00.000;1663;2014-10-09 12:38:46.000;A;"
                    ";0;0;D/275
```

I need using a DOS batch file this new output:

```
2014-10-09 00:00:00.000;1663;2014-10-09 12:38:46.000;A;"";0;0;E/272

2014-10-09 00:00:00.000;1663;2014-10-09 12:38:46.000;A;"";0;0;D/275
```

And I have tried this solution:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (oldfile.txt) do (
echo/|set /p ="%%a%"
)>>newfile.txt
```

But the output is wrong, I don't have two lines in txt newfile but only one line:

```
2014-10-09 00:00:00.000;1663;2014-10-09 12:38:46.000;A;"";0;0;E/2722014-10-09 00:00:00.000;1663;2014-10-09 12:38:46.000;A;"";0;0;D/275
```

What am I missing?

What's wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. New lines in double quoted values are absolutely valid in [CSV files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).
2. Why not using a text editor which supports Perl regular expression replaces?
   For example running a Perl regular expression replace using as search string `(?<=")\s+(?=";)` and an empty string as replace string would do the job.
3. There are console applications written for replacing strings in files. See
   [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60034/3074564)

But if you want to do this with a batch file for some unknown reason, take a look on batch code below working for your example.

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "INTEXTFILE=oldfile.txt"

if not exist "%INTEXTFILE%" goto EndBatch

set "OUTTEXTFILE=newfile.txt"
if exist "%OUTTEXTFILE%" del "%OUTTEXTFILE%"

set "FirstLine="
set "EndFirstLine=""
set "BeginSecondLine=                    ";"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%INTEXTFILE%") do (
    set "Line=%%A"
    if not "!FirstLine!"=="" (
        if "!Line:~0,22!"=="!BeginSecondLine!" (
            set "FirstLine=!FirstLine!!Line:~20!"
            echo !FirstLine!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
            set "Line="
        ) else (
            echo !FirstLine!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
        )
        set "FirstLine="
    )
    if not "!Line!"=="" (
        if "!Line:~-1!"=="!EndFirstLine!" (
            set "FirstLine=!Line!"
        ) else (
            echo !Line!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
        )
    )
)

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Empty lines are removed by this batch file, too. This cannot be avoided as command `for` ignores empty lines on parsing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Empty lines may get ignored, but can be re appended by using echo.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%INTEXTFILE%") do (
    set "Line=%%A"
    if not "!FirstLine!"=="" (
        if "!Line:~0,22!"=="!BeginSecondLine!" (
            set "FirstLine=!FirstLine!!Line:~20!"
            echo !FirstLine!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
            echo. >>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
            set "Line="
        ) else (
            echo !FirstLine!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
            echo. >>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
            set "FirstLine="
        )
    )
    if no    t "!Line!"=="" (
        if "!Line:~-1!"=="!EndFirstLine!" (
            set "FirstLine=!Line!"
        ) else (
            echo !Line!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
            echo. >>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
        )
    )
)
```